# Multiple columns in a single WHEN clause while using CASE in oracle

Tags: oracle, case

Can we use more than one column in a single `WHEN` clause while using `CASE` in oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CASE` expression can use more than one column in its *logic*, e.g.

```
CASE WHEN col1 > val1 AND col2 > val2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

But a `CASE` expression must *return* a single scalar value.

Comment: Exactly that's what has worked for me...Thanks a lot for such prompt help...Sorry that  couldn't upvote ur answer as I dont have enough reputation.. :)

Answer (score 0):

no you cant, but you can use multi when clause statement like this:

```
select
case when .... end col_a,
case when .... end col_b
from
xxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. For example:

```
select ...
from   emp
where case when bonus is null then salary else salary + bonus end > 4000
```

Here `emp` is a table, and `bonus` and `salary` are two of the columns in that table. The same WHERE clause can be expressed more simply, but regardless of reformulation, it will refer to both columns. (And there will be a CASE of some sort somewhere - NVL and COALESCE are CASE expressions with a different syntax.)